# Ensuring that.net librdkafka application is TLS encrypted

Tags: .net, ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I developing an application using librdkafka .net client which is connecting to kafka cluster running in linux os. I have exposed below two keys to encrypt the data:
{"security.protocol", "SSL" },
{"ssl.ca.location", "ca-cert path" }

By using the ca-cert and pointing to the port that ssl was exposed, I was able to connect and produce/consume messages. However I want to validate if my messages are really getting encrypted. How can I ensure that data is encrypted indeed?

Comment: You might get more responses if your provide some code. What have you tried so far, what isn't working. Otherwise this is way too broad a question.

Comment: Exact versions in use, and Linux distribution, might be relevant also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect to the Kafka cluster using TLS (with `security.protocol` set to SSL) all the **traffic** (including messages) between your client and Kafka is encrypted.

That said, this only covers the connection to Kafka. Once on the Kafka brokers, the data is plaintext. Depending on your cluster configuration it could be stored on encrypted disks or not.

If you want the data to be encrypted end to end, you'll have to encrypt it on the producer side and send the encrypted data to Kafka. Then when the consumer receives it, you'll have to decrypt it.

Comment: Yes Mickael, but I want to make sure that the traffic between client and kafka is encrypted. I used fiddler but I could not spot any difference at all. Should I use some other sniffing tool?